# Error in Autoform insert

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am having a problem getting my Insert Autoform to work properply. I am trying to have it similar to the example http://autoform.meteor.com/insertaf and my code is below. I have already removed insecure and autopublish

```
client/templates/venues/venue_submit.html

<template name="venueSubmit">
    <!-- {{> quickForm collection="Venues" id="venueSubmit" type="insert"}} -->
    {{#if isSuccessfulvenueSubmit }}
    <h2>Thanks for the Venue </h2>

    {{else}}
      {{#autoForm id="insertVenueForm" type="insert" collection=Collections.Venues omitFields="createdAt" resetOnSuccess=true}}

   {{> afQuickField name="Venue"}}

<div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Venue</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
        </div>
      {{/autoForm}}
    {{/if}}
</template>


client/templates/venues/venue_submit.js
        Schemas = {};

    Template.registerHelper("Schemas", Schemas);

    Schemas.Venue = new SimpleSchema({
      Venue: {
        type: String,
        label: "Venue Name",
        max: 200,
        autoform: {
          placeholder: "Name of the Venue"
        }
      },
....
});
AutoForm.debug()

var Collections = {};

Template.registerHelper("Collections", Collections);

Venues = Collections.Venues = new Mongo.Collection("Venues");
Venues.attachSchema(Schemas.Venue);

Venues.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userID, doc, fields, modifier) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
  }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("Venues")
};

server/Publications.js
Meteor.publish('venue', function () {
  return Venues.find(id);
});
```

[image: Error Message I get]

Comment: I don't think you're showing enough code for this to be reproduced.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Please show the `afFieldInput` for the Venue field.  Your code works fine for me, but I had to fill in the blanks.  Your issue is probably somewhere in those blanks.

Comment: I just added it and I think the issue is me not being sure where to place the files. I have added their locations above.

Answer (score 0):

The AutoForm `insert` type generates a document and inserts in on the client. Without the `autopublish` and `insecure` packages installed you need to make sure to subscribe to the appropriate collection on the client. It does not exist if you do not subscribe to it.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("Venues")
}
```

Comment: If my code is set up similar to the example, would that just go at the bottom of venue_submit.js file?

Comment: Yes that should work, as long as that code is executed on the client.

Comment: I added it above right after my allow statement, but I am still having the same issue when I try to implement it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Each of these files are in a shared client/server directory?

Comment: No the first two are client side and the publication is server side. I am not sure how to split the files to get them to be shared. I tried to put the first two files in the lib folder, but I get a lot more errors relating to Template not being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have venue_submit.js inside the client folder, but its contents are not intended solely for the client.

You can leave venue_submit.html exactly as it is.
Change venue_submit.js to:

```
Template.registerHelper("Schemas", Schemas);
AutoForm.debug();
Template.registerHelper("Collections", Collections);
Meteor.subscribe("Venues");
```

You only need the lines here that relate to the client: the two template helpers, the AutoForm debug (which you don't need except for debugging), and the subscribe to the Venues collection.

Change server/Publications.js to include everything related to the server side:

```
Meteor.publish('Venues', function () {
  return Venues.find({});
});

Venues.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userID, doc, fields, modifier) {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
  }
});
```

It includes the publish function and the permissions on the collection.

Now create lib/schema.js:

```
Schemas = {};

Schemas.Venue = new SimpleSchema({
      Venue: {
        type: String,
        label: "Venue Name",
        max: 200,
        autoform: {
          placeholder: "Name of the Venue"
        }
      }
});

Collections = {};

Venues = Collections.Venues = new Mongo.Collection("Venues");
Venues.attachSchema(Schemas.Venue);
```

Everything in `lib` will be available to both the client and server and the contents of this folder will be loaded first so the schema and collection definitions will be available to all the rest of the code.  Note the lack of a `var` keyword for the Collections.  Using `var` sets the scope to only within the file.  Omitting it makes the Collections variable available throughout your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. If I add form submission hooks, those would still go in the venue_submit.js file right? Finally, if I run db.venues.find() within Mongo, after submitting a form, it does not return anything. If I add, Venues.find().fetch() on a server file it will print out on the basic terminal. Is that a problem?

Comment: I corrected the Meteor.publish function.  You had it publishing using the name `venue`, then you subscribed to `Venues`.  These values need to match, so I changed the publish method to publish as `Venues`.  I also changed what it returns so that it returns the entire collection so you can see it on the client side.  On the mongo side, your collection is named Venues, not venues (see: `Mongo.Collection("Venues")`).  So you should use `db.Venues.find()`.  You could have seen that by running `show collections` in your database.  As for form submission hooks, yes, those still go in venue_submit.js

Comment: That cleared up all of the issues, but by returning the entire collection does that make the database insecure?

Comment: @jaysig: if you look at the example you cited (http://autoform.meteor.com/insertaf) the entire collection is returned. In fact the publication has no name in the publish function and is thus available to all clients.  Whether it is insecure depends on what you're trying to do.  If it's OK for all users to see all venues then it's not insecure.  If your Venue schema has an "owner" field and you only want users to see venues that they own, then you would edit the publish function to say `return Venues.find({owner: this.userId});`.